# If you do one Ajax sync call, do you need to add 'async:false' to all the other Ajax calls as well?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three ajax calls on the same script. I need to do this sync cause it gets some content to be processed after.......

```
 if(isHtmlFieldOnParentFull){
               //lleno el textarea con el valor del html input del campo html oculto de la ventana padre
               $editor.text(htmlInputParentValue); 
           }else{
            //lleno el input html de la ventana padre  con el html de la plantilla original para que se reemplazen las tags en el siguiente paso 
                 var request = $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '/editor/GetHtmlContentPlantilla',
                   async: false,
                   data: { id_acto_doc_plantilla:  getUrlVars()["id_acto_doc_plantilla"]
                        },
                success: function(data) {
                    $htmlInputParent.val(data);
                    },
                   error: function(data) {
                       alert("Error");
                        }
                     })
           }
```

but after that I have 2 more ajax calls as well. Should I really define them as

> async:false

as well? Cause I thought the first one would be blocking the executions of the other two until its callback, but I tried leaving the others without that parameter and it doesn't work, if I put every call as async:false then it works fine.

Comment: You should never do synchronous AJAX.  You need to learn how to write asynchronous code using promises.

Comment: I know, and I never do, but in this case I would like to know the answer for this......

Comment: You can make the other AJAX request from within the first one, and similarly the third one from the second one.

Comment: oohh, ok, so that's the way, you just chain them using the callbacks......I already avoided it's use but it's nice to know the answer cause you come across with this A LOT...If you want you can post it as an answer so I can mark you as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making subsequent AJAX calls from within the success callback of the current AJAX request and so on.
For example:

```
//first ajax

$.ajax({
 url: 'example.com',
 success: function(data){
  second_call();
 }
});

function second_call(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'example.com',
  success: function(data){
   third_call();
  }
 });
}

function third_call(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'example.com',
  success: function(data){
   //your code goes here
  }
 });
}
```